# Angular: Variable template inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

In my Angular template I use an attributive directive as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="my-template-one" my-template-directive></div>
```

JS:

```
// ...
.directive('myTemplateDirective', ['myconfig', function (myconfig) {
        return {
            templateUrl: myconfig.TEMPLATE_PATH + 'my-template-one.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                // code
            },
            controllerAs: 'dir'
        }
    }]);
```

For including another template, `my-template-two.html`, on another page, I would like to use *the same* directive. I do not want to duplicate the directive. How can I pass the template as an variable?

HTML on **another** page:

```
<div id="my-template-two" my-template-directive></div>
```

My goal is that somehow I can tell my directive to render `my-template-two.html` when this HTML is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `templateUrl` property  value may be a function which takes two arguments `tElement` and `tAttrs` and returns a string value:

```
app.directive('myTemplateDirective', ['myconfig', function (myconfig) {
    return {
        templateUrl: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
            var template = "my-template-one.html";
            if (tAttrs.use) {
                template = tAttrs.use;
            };             
            return myconfig.TEMPLATE_PATH + template;
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            // code
        },
        controllerAs: 'dir'
    }
}]);
```

### Usage

```
<div my-template-directive use="my-template-two.html"> </div>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)